# Custom To-Many Relationship Accessor Methods not called when delete rule is executed

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have a problem I don't understand..

I have a simple Core Data Model with Collection's and CD's. Every CD can be added to multiple Collections, so I added an intermediate object to make this possible. (edit: This is a simplification of my DataModel. The intermediate object is needed for nesting collections in collections)

So when a CD is added to a Collection it looks like this:
(IM is the intermediate object)

```
|==========|         |==========|         |==========|
|          |         |          |         |          |
|Collection|=========|   IM     |=========|    CD    |
|          |         |          |         |          |
|==========|         |==========|         |==========|
```

I have set the delete rules so that if a CD is deleted by the user, the IM object is cascade deleted and with deleting the IM object, the collection property nilled. That is behaving like I wanted it. No leftovers in the Database.

But the weird thing is that if I override the custom to-many relationship accessor method for removing the IM from the Collection (which I assumed would be called), nothing happens.

I am using what Apple provides in their Core Data Programming Guide.
[the link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdAccessorMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002154-SW6)

For Single object:

```
- (void)removeEmployeesObject:(Employee *)value
  {
      NSSet *changedObjects = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:&value count:1];
      [self willChangeValueForKey:@"employees"
            withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation
            usingObjects:changedObjects];
      [[self primitiveEmployees] removeObject:value];
      [self didChangeValueForKey:@"employees"
            withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation
            usingObjects:changedObjects];
}
```

for removing multiple objects:

```
- (void)removeEmployees:(NSSet *)value
  {
      [self willChangeValueForKey:@"employees"
            withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation
            usingObjects:value];
      [[self primitiveEmployees] minusSet:value];
      [self didChangeValueForKey:@"employees"
            withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation
            usingObjects:value];
}
```

(taken from the pdf, they use Employee as a to-many relation here)

But these methods are not called when the delete rules are executed!

So my Question: The IM object is cascade deleted, but these methods are not used. How can I detect this deletion action that Core Data does?

Is there another way?

I want to know this because I want to set a "dirtyFlag" on all Collection's that have been changed, so I can update some things for those objects. (other properties, won't explain here)

(KVO on the object would be useless. I can't go observing the complete DataBase, can I?. Or should the Collection object KVO itself for this property?)

Hope someone can help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively, you could implement `-prepareForDeletion` in your IM managedObject subclass.
`-prepareForDeletion` is automatically called by Core Data on a managedObject just before it's deleted from it's managedObjectContext.

When `-prepareForDeletion` is called, all relationships are still available and you could send a custom `-willDeleteIntermediateObject:` message to all of the containing Collections, passing `self` as a parameter.

You could then implement `-[Collection willDeleteIntermediateObject:]` to check if it's the last IM object it contains and if so, make it delete itself from it's managedObjectContext.

```
// IM.m
- (void)prepareForDeletion {
    [super prepareForDeletion];

    for (Collection *collection in self.collections) {
        [collection willDeleteIntermediateObject:self];
    }
}

// Collection.m
- (void)willDeleteIntermediateObject:(IM *)im {
    if (self.intermediateObjects.count == 1 && [self.intermediateObjects.containsObject:im]) {
        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:self];
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note that `self.intermediateObjects.count` gives the number of IM objects in the collection **before** deleting this instance. So compare to 2 if you need to delete a collection that will contain one IM object after deleting this one

Answer (score 1):

Are you modifying your data using fetched properties? The mutable collection accessor methods won't be called in that case.

If you want to set the dirty flag on literally every deletion, it might be a better pattern to simply register for the `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` notification. Use the `NSDeletedObjectsKey` key to get the deleted objects out of the `userInfo` dictionary. You can set the dirty flag on their collections at that time.

Comment: Thnx Aaron. I will investigate if this can be my solution. Say a user added 2 CD's to a Collection. And Deletes 1 CD from that Collection. My logic dictates that a Collection with 1 CD can be removed. So I scan the database for these cases, and delete those items. Which will trigger a Notification again. So I am afraid I end up in this loop and I wanted to be more efficient. So put in a while loop: when there are "dirty" Collections, scan those and delete Collection with only 1 CD. And start the while loop again. I hope I explain myself clearly. I will try what you suggested. Thanx!!!

Comment: ps I am not sure what you mean with "modifying your data using fetched properties"

Comment: I'd avoid spending time optimizing unless you're sure you actually have a *measurable* inefficiency. [See this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html) about fetched properties.

Comment: Thanks for the link Aaron. No, I am not using fetched properties.